# Breaking text into chunks using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will take a longish string that contains space separated words and break it into chunks of up to 50 characters that end with a space or the end of the line.

I first came up with: `(.{0,50}(\s|$))` but that only grabbed the first match.  I then thought I would add a `*` to the end: `(.{0,50}(\s|$))*` but now it grabs the entire string.

I've been testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/cW5aO9/1), but can't seem to to get it to work as needed.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: [I think you skipped `g` flag](https://regex101.com/r/cW5aO9/2)

Comment: @Abe: Maybe [this demo](http://ideone.com/c1jXwD) will help (here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV8aA1/1)).

Comment: @anubhava you want an extra set of parenthesis around your expression, then regex101 gives you all matches neatly down the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it seems to be working:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(.{0,50}[\s|$])')
test_str = u"jasdljasjdlk jal skdjl ajdl kajsldja lksjdlkasd jas lkjdalsjdalksjdalksjdlaksjdk sakdjakl jd fgdfgdfg\nhgkjd fdkfhgk dhgkjhdfhg kdhfgk jdfghdfkjghjf dfjhgkdhf hkdfhgkj jkdfgk jfgkfg dfkghk hdfkgh d asdada \ndkjfghdkhg khdfkghkd hgkdfhgkdhfk k dfghkdfgh dfgdfgdfgd\n"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Just use your old expression, with the findall. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to match the regex? The `re.findall()` method should return what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not using a regex, but have you thought about using `textwrap.wrap()`?

```
In [8]: import textwrap

        text = ' '.join([
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et convallis",
           "lectus. Quisque maximus diam ut sodales tincidunt. Integer ac finibus",
           "elit. Etiam tristique euismod justo, vel pretium tellus malesuada et.",
           "Pellentesque id mattis eros, at bibendum mauris. In luctus lorem eget nisl",
           "sagittis sollicitudin. Aenean consequat at lacus at porttitor. Nunc sit",
           "amet neque eu sem venenatis rutrum. Proin sed tempus lacus, sit amet porta",
           "velit. Suspendisse et semper nisl, eu varius orci. Ut non metus."])

In [9]: textwrap.wrap(text, 50)
Out[9]: ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing',
        'elit. Sed et convallis lectus. Quisque maximus',
        'diam ut sodales tincidunt. Integer ac finibus',
        'elit. Etiam tristique euismod justo, vel pretium',
        'tellus malesuada et. Pellentesque id mattis eros,',
        'at bibendum mauris. In luctus lorem eget nisl',
        'sagittis sollicitudin. Aenean consequat at lacus',
        'at porttitor. Nunc sit amet neque eu sem venenatis',
        'rutrum. Proin sed tempus lacus, sit amet porta',
        'velit. Suspendisse et semper nisl, eu varius orci.',
        'Ut non metus.']
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you need - '[^\s]{1,50}'.
Example on smaller number:

```
>>> text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor"
>>> splitter = re.compile('[^\s]{1,3}')
>>> splitter.findall(text)
['Lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'sit', 'dol', 'or']
```